# Is there a way to insert data with relations in Micronaut Data JPA WITHOUT querying first?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, micronaut

I've used Spring Data JPA in the past and I'm trying to apply those experience to Micronaut Data JPA, but I'm experiencing some difficulties.

I have set up two "Domains" in my project like this(yes I'm using lombok):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@Serdeable
@ToString
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Parent_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Parent_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("sequence asc")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and the accompanying child:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Serdeable
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Child_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Child_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "sequence")
    private Integer sequence;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Simply put, Parent class have a One-To-Many relationship with Child.

After creating assorted Repository interface that extends JpaRepository,the Parent part works fine, and I saved a Parent entity into database.

The problem occurs when I try to do save the child with parent's id.

Here is what I'm doing right now:

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setId(parentId);
child.setParent(parent);
childRepository.save(child);
```

I created a empty Parent, set it's id, then feed it to child before saving it.

As I remember, the similar action would result in a new record in Child with it's parent_id set to given parentId.

But instead I got a new record created in Parent and a new record in Child with it's parent_id set to that new Parent's id.

Now I could do this and get what I want:

```
parentRepository.findById(parentId).ifPresent(child::setParent);
```

But that would result in an extra step of querying the database, which doesn't seem to be efficient.

chat-gpt tells me to remove GeneratedValue annotation but I don't think that's correct.

It's there a way to save child and have the parent_id set properly without the extra step?

**update**

The repository are like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent,Long> {
}
```

It's literally empty. I was hoping it would work exactlly like it's Spring Data counterpart.

Comment: Can you add your repositories to the question or better yet a link to a sample project?

Comment: We switched to JDBC and ignored the JPA Relation "magic" to have better control on it especially for parent_ids and relations and so on.

Comment: @ShingJo I've added the repositories, they're empty just like this in the original project.